# Autocomplete on phone - AS3

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, autocomplete

I've made an autocomplete that work very well in the swf file.

[image]

very simple, when the user write the first letter, a suggestion is made with words.

I've published my project for IOS. 
When I'm trying it **on the Iphone**, nothing is suggested when I'm typing the first letter. 
I have to write the first letter and then clicked on "enter" in order to display the suggestions...

**I don't want the users to "validate" in order to have the suggestion but simply by typing a letter.**

Do you know what could be the problem ? Anyone can help me ?
Weirdly, **I've tried on an Android device**, and **it's working perfectly well** ! (like my swf).

Here is my code :

```
urlLoader.load(new URLRequest("test.txt"));
            urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadComplete);
            inputField.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, suggest);

 function loadComplete(e:Event):void
        {
            suggestions = e.target.data.split(",");
        }

         function suggest(e:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            suggested = [];

            for (var i:int = 0; i < textfields.length; i++)
            {
                removeChild(textfields[i]);
            }

            textfields = [];

            for (var j:int = 0; j < suggestions.length; j++)
            {
                if (suggestions[j].indexOf(inputField.text.toLowerCase()) == 0)
                {
                    var term:TextField = new TextField();
                    term.width = 300;
                    term.height = 20;
                    term.x = 70;
                    term.y = (20 * suggested.length) + 314;
                    term.border = true;
                    term.borderColor = 0x353535;
                    term.background = true;
                    term.backgroundColor = 0xFF9900;
                    term.textColor = 0x4C311D;
                    term.defaultTextFormat = format;

                    term.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, useWord);
                    term.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, hover);
                    term.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, out);
                    term.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, tellMe);

                    addChild(term);
                    textfields.push(term);

                    suggested.push(suggestions[j]);

                    term.text = suggestions[j];
                }

            }

            if (inputField.length == 0)
            {
                suggested = [];

                for (var k:int = 0; k < textfields.length; k++)
                {
                    removeChild(textfields[k]);
                }

                textfields = [];
            }

            if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN && currentSelection < textfields.length-1)
            {
                currentSelection++;
                textfields[currentSelection].textColor = 0x4C311D;
            }

            if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.UP && currentSelection > 0)
            {
                currentSelection--;
                textfields[currentSelection].textColor = 0x4C311D;
            }

            if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.ENTER)
            {
                inputField.text = textfields[currentSelection].text;

                suggested = [];

                for (var l:int = 0; l < textfields.length; l++)
                {
                    removeChild(textfields[l]);
                }

                textfields = [];
                currentSelection = 0;
            }
        }

         function useWord(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            inputField.text = e.target.text;

            suggested = [];

            for (var i:int = 0; i < textfields.length; i++)
            {
                removeChild(textfields[i]);
            }

            textfields = [];
        }
```

Thank you

EDIT

Here's my new code with Stagetext

```
var myTextField:StageText = new StageText();
         var stageTextInitOptions:StageTextInitOptions;
         var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
         var suggestions:Array = new Array();
         var suggested:Array = new Array();
         var textfields:Array = new Array();
         var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
         var currentSelection:int = -1;
         var searchChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();


            myTextField.returnKeyLabel = ReturnKeyLabel.SEARCH;
            myTextField.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, suggest);
            stageTextInitOptions = new StageTextInitOptions(false);
            myTextField = new StageText(stageTextInitOptions);
            myTextField.softKeyboardType = SoftKeyboardType.DEFAULT;
            myTextField.returnKeyLabel = ReturnKeyLabel.DONE;
            myTextField.autoCorrect = true;
            myTextField.fontSize = 20;
            myTextField.color = 0x000000;
            myTextField.fontWeight = "bold";
            myTextField.stage = this.stage;
            myTextField.viewPort = new Rectangle(25, 108, stage.stageWidth-40, 28);



            urlLoader.load(new URLRequest("Sports2.txt"));
            urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadComplete);
            myTextField.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, suggest);
```

Comment: I have little experience with AIR for mobile, but I don't think KeyboardEvents fire on iOS. Alternatively, consider `StageText`, or listen for `Event.CHANGE`

Comment: Yep no keyboard event on mobile, also you are using TextField instance which are not made to work on mobile. StageText has been made to remedy this problem and offer true textField behavior on mobile.

Comment: Same thing. I've made a StageText but on IOS, I have to click on "finished" on the keyboard in order to see the suggestions... Any other ideas (I've edited my post with the new code)

Comment: It's working ! With the Event.CHANGE ! Thank you Jacob and BotMaster

Answer (score 0):

KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT doesn't really works at iOS. KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN is dispatching only on some keys. I saw only key "Enter".